# Kubernetes error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 30: could not find expected ':'

Tags: kubernetes

I'm starting my journey with kubernetes and i'm stuck with deploying my application.
From my perspective there is no error in the code but seems like kubernetes has diffrent opinion on that.

Please have a look:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mq-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: mq
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mq-test
  labels:
    app: mq
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mq
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: store/ibmcorp/mqadvanced-server-dev:9.1.2.0
          name: queue-man
          env:
          - name: LICENSE
            value: accept
          - name: MQ_QMGR_NAME
            value: QM1
          ports:
          - containerPort: 1414
          volumeMounts:
          - name: mqdata
            mountPath:/mnt/mqm
      volumes:
      - name: mqdata
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mq-pv-claim
```

The error i get is:
`error parsing .\mq.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 30: could not find expected ':'`

The line no. 30 is `spec:` which obviously has got the ':'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yaml is not properly indented. Below should work.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: store/ibmcorp/mqadvanced-server-dev:9.1.2.0
    name: queue-man
    env:
    - name: LICENSE
      value: accept
    - name: MQ_QMGR_NAME
      value: QM1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 1414
```